# Can you double stack in F1 Online (in F1 2018)?

Tags: f1-2018

In F1 2018, when playing online, can you double stack? (Where both cars from the same team pit at the same time, making one of the cars have to wait for the first car to have finished it's stop before it can pitstop)

The question arises because it would seem that for realism you could, but in a gameplay sense it doesn't work since your 'teammate' in an online race is not really a teammate. He could just jump in the pits at the same time as you, screwing you (or himself) over.

So can you or can you not double stack in Online F1 2018 Races?

Comment: Please restrict your question to only one game, it is too broad to be answered right now

Comment: With the tags, it's meaning more about f1-2018, which is the one used currently in F1 Esports.

Comment: Could you edit your question to reflect that?

Comment: See title. Think it cant be missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at YouTube videos of F1 2018 players, it seems like it is possible to double stack. This is the only subject-specific video I could find, but I suspect longer Let's Play videos might showcase double stacking as well.

[YouTube video: "Double Stack Pit-Stop F1 2018 Game"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7n5GP3v8yd0)

I suspect the mechanic would be similar whether it's an online or local race, wherein  the first car to pit would pit first while the second one waits behind for the first one to  pit.

Although it would make sense as you mentioned for double-stacking to be disabled in non-league online races  as  you don't truly have a "teammate". Ideally through an existing mechanic already implemented in the game like ghosting. Don't know what the state of the game is nowadays though.